# Build Parent UIViewController with fixed UIView headers and Footers. Adjusting inheriting UIViewControllers content within the header and footer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have built a Base UIViewController which has a fixed UIView header and footer and this is working fine.

Now UIViewController which inherits from the base controller has footer and the header but the contents of the inheriting controller overlaps with the footer and header.

I want that the content of the inheriting view controller to automatically adjust between the base classes header and footer.

Can anybody give me any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody ever posted an answer to my question. I'll answer it myself.

What i ended up doing was created a BaseUIViewController.
In the controller, i added

1. Header View -- Added Top Constraints
2. Container View  -- Pinned it between the header and the footer.
3. Footer View -- Added Bottom Constraints

Now when building a new controller, i add BaseUIViewController as the super class and added all my view inside the container view. Thus making all my content always dynamically fit into the container.